# Capacitance per unit area and CMOS case

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductor-physics, capacitance, electrical-engineering

In a modern 0.35 μm [CMOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMOS) processor the gate oxide thickness is around 80 Å = 8 nm. This gives us a capacitance per unit area of $430~\mathrm{nF/cm^2}$

I am not getting how one gets this capacitance per unit area. Can anyone explain this? (i.e. how formula are constructed and used.)

Comment: Perhaps http://electronics.stackexchange.com is a better home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capacitance of area A, dielectric thickness d is,
$$
C=\frac{\epsilon_{0}\epsilon_{r}A}{d}
$$
where permittivity of free space is $\epsilon_{0}=8.85\times 10^{-12} {\rm~F/m}$ and the relative permittivity of silicon dioxide is $\epsilon_{r}=4.5$ at $f=1{\rm~kHz}$ (Kaye and Laby 14th edition). Put $A=1{\rm~cm}^{2}$, $d=8{\rm~nm}$ and one gets $C=498{\rm~nF}$. I guess the overestimate is because the relative permittivity is less at higher frequencies typical of ICs.